# How to reuse equal pending http requests observable in angular 4

Tags: angular, http, rxjs, angular2-observables

In my project, sometimes because of mistakes that I make or a newer team member makes, there are cases when there is an http request with some specific parameters being send to the remote backend more than once at the same time (meaning there the same exacty request will appear in the browser http requests in dev tools twice as pending).

This kind of cases are bad for us, and it caused us problems before in cases where the remote was answering this requests in a rate that was slower than the interval that was sending them.

The obvious solution here is to always make sure we get an answer of a requst of some type before sending the next request of same type (and params). But I was thinking there should be a way to make sure in a generic way, that if some request is about to be send with the angular http service, if that request already exists with pending status, the service could return the SAME observable that was returned by the previous request that is already pending (which will solve some messy cases when I have 2 different and unrelated components making the same request one after another, this will make them both subscribe to the same observable).

We already have a service that wraps all uses we have in our project with http.

The question is how I could achieve this kind of behavior (or if for some reason my idea is wrong and maybe I shouldn't aim to get such behavior?), i'm looking for the most simple solution available (maybe there is something already implmented by angular to achieve this that I missed?) or in case there isn't some kind of obserable based solution that checked for each request we are about to make if the request already exists with pending status

Comment: Please format this question using paragraphs, etc.

Comment: Is it understandable now?

Comment: You might find this interesting: https://hackernoon.com/angular-simple-in-memory-cache-service-on-the-ui-with-rxjs-77f167387e39

Comment: This might be what im looking for, I was only looking for the solution of point 4 in the link about preventing the case of having 2 identical requests with oending status, I saw some functions jn the source about checking in flight request but I couldn't wrap my head around how the code checks if the request exists in pending status. If you could focus me to how you achieve that it could really set me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to suggest [`switchMap`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-switchMap), but [`distinctUntilChanged`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-distinctUntilChanged) will help in this specific case because we want to make a request when arguments are different. I assume that arguments are coming from another observable.

```
Rx.Observable
  .interval(300) // every 300ms
  .mapTo(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) // emit a number from 0 to 9
  .distinctUntilChanged() // if number is the same, ignore it
  .flatMap(number => this.exampleService.makeRequest(number)) // make a request for a unique number
  .subscribe(response => console.log(response)); // log response
```

Comment: I cant understand how this example of a cade is an answer to the question

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be in multiple subscription:

```
var res = this.myService.get();
var firstSubscription = res.subscribe(); // first http call
var firstSubscription = res.subscribe(); // second
```

Try to use Multicasting Operators:

```
var resShared = this.myService.get().share();
```

Comment: From my understanding this solution is only for when 2 parts of my code work with the same observable that is a result of an http call. This won't help if 2 unrelated components make the same http call because they will get 2 different observable because that's the default http service behavior, so this answer is not solving the question at all